# Keycloak on kubernetes behind ingress doesn't work

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, keycloak, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm having trouble setting up keycloak on Kubernetes. I have a load balancer set up (nginx ingress controller) that terminates SSL. I've tried many different configurations but all I'm getting is 502, 503 and 404 errors when I try the /auth endpoint. Here is my deployment.yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: keycloak
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: keycloak
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: keycloak
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: keycloak
        image: bitnami/keycloak:13.0.1-debian-10-r79
        env:
        - name: KEYCLOAK_USER
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: keycloak-secret
              key: keycloak_user
        - name: KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: keycloak-secret
              key: keycloak_password
        - name: PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING
          value: "true"
        - name: DB_VENDOR
          value: "postgres"
        - name: DB_ADDR
          value: "my.postgres.host"
        - name: DB_DATABASE
          value: "keycloak"
        - name: DB_USER
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: keycloak-secret
              key: dbuser
        - name: DB_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: keycloak-secret
              key: dbpassword
        - name: KEYCLOAK_LOGLEVEL
          value: "DEBUG"
        - name: KEYCLOAK_EXTRA_ARGS
          value: "-Dkeycloak.frontendUrl=https://my.keycloak.local/auth"
        ports:
          - name: http
            containerPort: 8080
          - name: https
            containerPort: 8443
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  labels:
    app: keycloak
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    name: http
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: keycloak
```

and my ingress.yaml:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.org/server-snippets: |
      location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      }
  name: ingress
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
      - my.keycloak.local
  rules:
  - host: my.keycloak.local
    http:
      paths:
      - path: "/"
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: keycloak
            port:
              number: 8080
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here. I've followed some discussions on GitHub regarding this issue but I still can't find a solution. This particular configuartion that I provided is returning 404 not found when I access https://my.keycloak.local/auth.

What I can tell is that this is definitely an issue with keycloak - I substituted the keycloak image with a nginx:alpine docker image and everything is working correctly - the "Welcome to nginx!" page loads.

I'll gladly provide more info if needed. My kubernetes cluster is running on AKS.

Comment: Can you post the pod logs from keycloak and show the http responses?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/hi5E4qi7 Here are the logs you asked for. In this particular config that I've provided, nginx returns 404 for /auth endpoint. If I change everything to go through port 80, I get a 502.

Answer (score 2):

Well after reading the keycloak logs more carefully my problem is resolved. Turns out that keycloak doesn't start properly (even though the state of the pod was Running 1/1") if the pod name is longer than 23 characters. After changing Deployment resource to a StatefulSet and choosing a  ServiceName, my problems went away, keycloak started properly and I can access it.

Comment: Hi,I am using nginx ingress with tls. I see following error: Startup probe failed: Get "http://10.233.75.63:8080/auth/": dial tcp 10.233.75.63:8080: connect: connection refused.